# Lockbits doesn't affect my Image

Tags: c#, pointers, image-processing, lockbits

I'm building a 3d (red,cyan) program. It went well, but when combining, the "image" (see in code) doesn't seemed to be affected.

What is my mistake?

Assume:

```
RImage_P(point) = {5,5}
startCyan(point) = {0,0}
startRed(point) = {5,5}
```

`CImage`, `RImage` are below the code.
Image result is a fully black transparent image. 
For testing and debugging, I have commented the Alpha (the results are the same).

```
private void bitCombine(System.Drawing.Point startCyan, System.Drawing.Point startRed)
{
    using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(CImage.Width + Math.Abs(RImage_P.X), CImage.Height + Math.Abs(RImage_P.Y),PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        var rectfull = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, CImage.Width, CImage.Height);
        var bitsC = CImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
                                    , PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var bitsA = alpha.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
                                    , PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var bitsOutput = image.LockBits(rectfull, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly
                                    , PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        unsafe
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < CImage.Height; y++)
            {
                byte* ptrC = (byte*)bitsC.Scan0 +  y * bitsC.Stride;
                byte* ptrA = (byte*)bitsA.Scan0 +  y * bitsA.Stride;
                byte* ptrOutput = (byte*)bitsOutput.Scan0 
                                    + (y+startCyan.Y)* bitsOutput.Stride;
                for (int x = 0; x < CImage.Width; x++)// cyan values
                {// gui+ is reversed BGRA
                    ptrOutput[4 * (x+startCyan.X)] = ptrC[4 * x];           // blue
                    ptrOutput[4 * (x + startCyan.X) + 1] = ptrC[4 * x + 1];// green
                    //ptrOutput[4 * (x + startCyan.X) + 3] = ptrA[4 * x + 3];// alpha
                }
            }
            CImage.UnlockBits(bitsC);

            var bitsR = RImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
                                        , PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            for (int y = 0; y < RImage.Height; y++)// red values
            {
                byte* ptrR = (byte*)bitsR.Scan0 + y  * bitsR.Stride;
                byte* ptrA = (byte*)bitsA.Scan0 + y  * bitsA.Stride;
                byte* ptrOutput = (byte*)bitsOutput.Scan0
                                    + (y+ startRed.Y) * bitsOutput.Stride;
                for (int x = 0; x < RImage.Width; x++)
                {// gui+ is reversed BGRA
                    ptrOutput[4 * (x + startRed.X) + 2] = ptrR[4 * x + 2];   // red
                    //ptrOutput[4 * (x + startRed.X) + 3] = ptrA[4 * x + 3];// alpha
                }
            }

            RImage.UnlockBits(bitsR);
            alpha.UnlockBits(bitsA);
            image.UnlockBits(bitsOutput);


            this.image = image;
        }
    }
}
```

The images:

[image: CIamge]
[image: RImage]

Comment: The posted code will never set blue and alpha, the alpha at 0 will produce a black image.  Debug your code by starting with a very small bitmap so you can keep track of input and output better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out with an image visualizer that it does work, but the alpha channel is =0
the answer is to change the alpha channel's value to 255.